# Copy old data from local Centos to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: linux, centos7, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have the following task to complete. I hope someone can provide the feedback to get me started.

- We have a directory with thousands of images in many folders and sub-folders
- The goal is to have a script run through the images and move anything older than 1 year to AWS S3
- The directory structure should be preserved in S3 and the images should be removed from the source.

PS: I already have a connection to AWS from the instance and the IAM user was created as well.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: Use [`rclone`](https://rclone.org/s3/). To move files or directories instead of sync/copying those, use [`rclone move`](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_move/). See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/754690/rsync-to-aws-s3-bucket/847308#847308).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rsync to AWS S3 bucket](https://serverfault.com/questions/754690/rsync-to-aws-s3-bucket)